# Open desktop version in iframe on mobile browser for embed Polarsteps

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, embed, user-agent

I have an embed link of my PolarSteps profil on my website as an iframe. It's working perfectly fine on desktop. On mobile browser like Safari and Chrome, Polarsteps is no longer navigable, but every click on the iframe will open a new tab with the Polarsteps site. When I switch to desktop version on my phone in Chrome, it works as expected though. How can I trick Polarsteps to always show the desktop version.
My code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>mytitle</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        iframe {
            width: 100dvw;
            height: 100dvh;
            border: 0px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="https://www.polarsteps.com/myname/myid/embed"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to fake the width, but I think they check the user agent. My understanding of this is limited and I understand that this may be not solvable, because I can't alter an iframe.

Comment: Can you give the real iframe URL, so that we can see for ourselves how this actually behaves?

Comment: Sure! I just didn't want to be accused of shameless advertising `<iframe src="https://www.polarsteps.com/Rainer124/9108584-rainers-rucksackreise/embed"></iframe>`
Thank you for looking into it!

Comment: Hm, that only gets me a spinner inside the iframe that never disappears, and an error in the console, `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.` Is this somehow made embedable _on_ specific domains only or something?